# Fundamental roles that astronomy played in the development of mathematics

Tags: physics, math-history

I'm currently a third year undergrad maths student, and am particularly interested in how astronomy changed maths as we know it today?

Are there any particular sources that could be recommended? Or even if someone could explain to me the fundamentals of maths that astronomy brought about. I know that it dates back as far as the Babylonians, but are there any significant periods of time that made a great difference?

Thanks

Comment: Historically until around the 1700s, the word "astronomer" or "astrologer" was usually used to refer to mathematicians so even the words themselves had much different connotations then they do today. This has in fact led to several miss translations, one of which, a miss translated quote by Christian theologian St. Augustine says that "The good Christian should beware the mathematician and all those who make empty prophecies. The danger already exists that the mathematicians have made a covenant with the devil to darken the spirit and to confine man in the bonds of hell."

Answer (score 1):

Astronomy has always been a powerful stimulus for the development of mathematical tools to solve problems arising from the natural sciences. The [Kerala school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala_school_of_astronomy_and_mathematics), motivated by problems in astronomy, already developed power series for a number of trigonometric functions centuries before the development of the calculus in the 17th century. In the early 17th century, [Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler) used [infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) to derive the [area law of planetary motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion). Most famously, of course, Newton used [infinitesimal calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_calculus) to derive his laws.

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometry was originally developed for solving problems in astronomy, and it took a long time before it was used for other purposes. Ptolemy's version of trigonometry was [chord tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_table), later [Indian astronomers or mathematicians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata%27s_sine_table) found that the sine function was more convenient to use.

Gauss developed the method of [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to solve the problem of computing the orbit of a planet from only a few observations.